# icons on the bottom of the responsive image ( always on the bottom of a bootstrap column )

Tags: image, responsive

Is it possible to make this 2 circles always on the right and left of the bottom of the image? They need to be always one on the bottom left, the second on the bottom right of an image- when I resize the image. (they should always stick to the bottom corners of an image) How to position them like that?

```
enter code here
```

Codepen:
`https://codepen.io/anami90/pen/KeEqRw?editors=1100`

Answer (score 0):

according to your quesrion the circles should appear on the outer column isnot it?
hope this helps:

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
.col-3 {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.col-6 {
  background: pink;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.circle-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.circle-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="circle-left"></div>
  <div class="col-6">

    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"/>

  </div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div class="circle-right"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zabLoq?editors=1100

Comment: Thank You but it is not what I mean. The circles should always be in the position as I draw below: https://ibb.co/n1TNey

Answer (score 0):

I would like to position this 2 circles as it is on this picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLkLc.jpg)